# Form validation with multiple if statements on an onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

During validation inside handleClick function with multiple if statements, only the last one set the errors state to true (errors.sintomas: true) even leaving blank all the inputs (the remaining ones leave it at false, the initial state of errors, thus preventing the inputs to get a red border expcept for the commented last one). So leaving all the inputs blank gives me an errors state of:

{
mascota: false,
propietario: false,
fecha: false,
hora: false,
sintomas: true
}

Why is this happening? This is all the code:

```
const Formulario = () => {
  const [cita, setCita] = useState({
    mascota: '',
    propietario: '',
    fecha: '',
    hora: '',
    sintomas: ''
  });

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    mascota: false,
    propietario: false,
    fecha: false,
    hora: false,
    sintomas: false
  });

  const [triggerAnim, setTriggerAnim] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setCita({ ...cita, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (cita.mascota.trim().length < 1) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, mascota: true });
      setTriggerAnim(true);
    }
    if (cita.propietario.trim().length < 1) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, propietario: true });
      setTriggerAnim(true);
    }
    if (cita.fecha.trim().length < 1) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, fecha: true });
      setTriggerAnim(true);
    }
    if (cita.hora.trim().length < 1) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, hora: true });
      setTriggerAnim(true);
    }
    if (cita.sintomas.trim().length < 1) {
      setErrors({ ...errors, sintomas: true });
      setTriggerAnim(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h2>Crear una cita</h2>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="mascota">Nombre de tu mascota:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="mascota"
          className={`u-full-width ${errors.mascota ? 'error' : ''}`}
          placeholder="Nombre de la mascota"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={cita.mascota}
        />
        <label htmlFor=" propietario">Nombre del propietario:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="propietario"
          className={`u-full-width ${errors.propietario ? 'error' : ''}`}
          placeholder="Nombre del propietario"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={cita.propietario}
        />
        <label htmlFor="fecha">Fecha:</label>
        <input
          type="date"
          name="fecha"
          className={`u-full-width ${errors.fecha ? 'error' : ''}`}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={cita.fecha}
        />
        <label htmlFor="hora">Hora:</label>
        <input
          type="time"
          name="hora"
          className={`u-full-width ${errors.hora ? 'error' : ''}`}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={cita.hora}
        />
        <label htmlFor="sintomas">Sintomas</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="sintomas"
          className={`u-full-width ${errors.sintomas ? 'error' : ''}`}
          placeholder="Síntomas de la mascota:"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={cita.sintomas}
        />    
 
        <button className="button-primary u-full-width" onClick={handleClick}>
          Crear Cita
        </button>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Formulario;
```

Don't understand why only the last if statement is working.
If I use setErrors(prevState => {return {...prevState, mascota: true}) (the callback with the previous state) then suddenly all works OK. Why using object spread operator to update state does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click once, the whole `handleClick` function will also run through its code fully once. Inside that one `handleClick`, the `errors` object is constant and is never mutated; it refers to what `errors` contained during the render *before the click*.

Say the initial `errors` object's values were all `false` the render before click. Then, if the click handler detects a `mascota` error:

```
setErrors({ ...errors, mascota: true });
```

will result in an object with all `false` properties, except for `mascota`, whose property is true.

Next, if there's a `propietario` error as well, the following will run:

```
setErrors({ ...errors, propietario: true });
```

which sets the state to the initial errors object (with all `false` values), combined with a single true property in `propietario`. The `mascota` property in the new state will be `false`, because the `errors` object that was referenced contained `mascota: false`, and it was combined with `propietario: true`. And so on.

You need the callback form so that the new state can be calculated properly *even if* it was just updated by a prior synchronous call of `setErrors`, otherwise those prior synchronous calls will not factor into the new state.

Rather than all of this manual validation, you might also consider adding `required` attributes to the inputs.